# Ical .ics non-readable by Office 365

Tags: outlook, google-calendar-api, phpmailer, icalendar

I'm trying to send a meeting request with an Ical and PhpMailer. I join the Ical as a StringAttachment with my mail. If i download the attachment, i can read it with a desktop Outlook but i try to open it with Office 365 and i have an alert that say : "The .ICS attachment can't be viewed because the format is not supported.". On google calendar i can't import it either.

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";  
$ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VTIMEZONE\r\n";
$ical .= "TZID:Europe/Paris\r\n";
$ical .= "X-LIC-LOCATION:Europe/Paris\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$ical .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0100\r\n";
$ical .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0200\r\n";
$ical .= "TZNAME:CEST\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTART:19700329T020000\r\n";
$ical .= "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=3\r\n";
$ical .= "END:DAYLIGHT\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:STANDARD\r\n";
$ical .= "TZOFFSETFROM:+0200\r\n";
$ical .= "TZOFFSETTO:+0100\r\n";
$ical .= "TZNAME:CET\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTART:19701025T030000\r\n";
$ical .= "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=-1SU;BYMONTH=10\r\n";
$ical .= "END:STANDARD\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VTIMEZONE\r\n"; 
$ical .= "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:hgdfsghdsfghsd@gmail.com\r\n";
$ical .= "ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:MAILTO:ghhgjkgh@gmail.com\r\n";
$ical .= "UID:".strtoupper(md5($interId))."-*****.fr\r\n";
$ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$ical .= "SEQUENCE:1";
$ical .= "STATUS:".$status."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTART:".$startDate->format('Ymd').'T'.$startDate->format('His')."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTEND:".$endDate->format('Ymd').'T'.$endDate->format('His')."\r\n";
$ical .= "LOCATION:".$shopName."\r\n";
$ical .= "SUMMARY:".$summary."\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
$ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

$mail->AddStringAttachment($ical, "Invite.ics", "base64", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST");
```

I want the invite to be readable by gmail and office 365, but I don't understand what's wrong with my ical. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose the problem if you provide an actual copy of a generated ICAL and more detailed error messages if you have.

Comment: I don't know how to test an ICAL and how get more error messages. The only error message i got is from office 365. But i uploaded the ICAL. The link is below:
http://www.filedropper.com/interventioninvite8

Answer (score 1):

A couple problems:

1) The DTSTART and DTEND properties in the VEVENT component are missing the TZID parameter.

```
$ical .= "DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Paris:".$startDate->format('Ymd').'T'.$startDate->format('His')."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTEND;TZID=Europe/Paris:".$endDate->format('Ymd').'T'.$endDate->format('His')."\r\n";
```

2) The VTIMEZONE component should not be inside of the VEVENT component.  It should be underneath the VCALENDAR component.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
...
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: It didn't resolve my problem but it give me an other error message "The .ICS attachment can't be viewed because it contains an item that's not calendar-related.". I try to remove the VTIMEZONE and the VALARM to see if they were the item but it doesn't work. Do you think it could be possible it is something missing that make Office365 think it's not calendar-related?

Comment: @RHau I don't see anything else that's wrong.  Can you include an example of an iCalendar file that your code generates?

Comment: Thanks for your help. You can download it here : http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=94423760895642163283

Comment: @RHau Don't know.  Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Your second error is likely caused by the METHOD property inside the VEVENT component. METHOD should only occur inside the VCALENADAR component.